# Making a vector of wires have the same value as one wire

Tags: verilog

I am making a circuit where I need multiple wires to take on the value of a single input wire.

Right now I assign them individually and it works, I was just curious if there's a better more efficient way to do it. My current code is shown below:

```
input [15:0] a;
wire [15:0] select;
assign select[0] = a[15];
assign select[1] = a[15];
assign select[2] = a[15];
assign select[3] = a[15];
assign select[4] = a[15];
assign select[5] = a[15];
assign select[6] = a[15];
assign select[7] = a[15];
assign select[8] = a[15];
assign select[9] = a[15];
assign select[10] = a[15];
assign select[11] = a[15];
assign select[12] = a[15];
assign select[13] = a[15];
assign select[14] = a[15];
assign select[15] = a[15];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the repeat operator:

```
assign select = {16{a[15]}};
```

This: `{16{..}}` produces the repeated concatenation of what is between the inner curly brackets.
Thus this: `{16{a[15]}}` concatenates a[15] sixteen times.

Answer (score 2):

While the repeat operator is the best and most obvious way to do this, you can also do it with a for loop inside a combinatorial always block:

```
input [15:0] a;
reg [15:0] select;

always @* begin
  for (int i=0; i<16; i++) begin
    select[i] = a[15];
  end
end
```

All these three solutions synthesize to the exact same result. While I recommend the repeat operator in this case, you might find this solution useful later if you need to do some more complex assignments.

Comment: I have changed my answer to use always @* instead of always_comb, to make the code compatible with standard Verilog.